# Visual Studio 2017 freeze when creating new project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, freeze

I am trying to create an Xamarin Forms application on Visual Studio 2017 15.5.4, but when i click create the application freeze and it says `Not Responding`. Also in the bottom of the Visual Studio says that `Creating project... project creating successfull`.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do without uninstall, reinstall, or repair. First, ensure you have all updates installed. If you do try launching from a command line start VS using devenv.exe. The following link is the switches available, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches.

First, try running with the default addins using: 
devenv /SafeMode

Second, reset addins that maybe being skipped:
devenv /ResetSkipPkgs

Last, try reseting back to default user settings. Although you should backup your settings:
devenv /ResetSettings